# Logical indexing using a mask works in numpy, not in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix-indexing

I'm trying to reproduce the following Python code in MATLAB, using a sparse matrix.

```
>>> print(M)
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
>>> im2var = np.arange(5 * 5).reshape((5, 5))
>>> A = np.zeros((25, 25), dtype=int)
>>> A[im2var[M == 1], im2var[M == 1]] = 1
>>> print(A)
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

This is what I've written in MATLAB

```
M = [
    0 0 0 0 0;
    0 1 1 1 0;
    0 1 0 1 0;
    0 1 1 1 0;
    0 0 0 0 0
];

im2var = reshape(1:25, [5 5]);
A = zeros(25, 25);
A(im2var(M == 1), im2var(M == 1)) = 1;
num2str(A)
```

When I run the MATLAB script, I get the following matrix, which is clearly different from the Numpy output.

```
ans =

  25x73 char array

    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
```

Thanks for any assistance!

EDIT: I would also like to accomplish the following effect, but the current answer doesn't seem to work for two sets of indices.

In Python:

```
>>> Mp = np.roll(M, 1, axis=1)
>>> A[im2var[M==1], im2var[Mp==1]] = -1
>>> print(A[5:15,5:15])
[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  1 -1  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  1 -1  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 -1]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
```

By using the current answer's suggestion, I wrote the following code.

```
M = [
    0 0 0 0 0;
    0 1 1 1 0;
    0 1 0 1 0;
    0 1 1 1 0;
    0 0 0 0 0
];

Mp = circshift(M, 1, 2);

ind = find(M);
indp = find(Mp);

A = zeros(25, 25);
A(sub2ind(size(A), ind, ind)) = 1;
A(sub2ind(size(A), ind, indp)) = -1;

num2str(A)
```

While the diagonal 1s have successfully showed up, the -1s are in the wrong place.

```
ans =

  25x73 char array

    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
```

EDIT 2:

According to the edited answer, I tried the following code.

```
M = [
    0 0 0 0 0;
    0 1 1 1 0;
    0 1 0 1 0;
    0 1 1 1 0;
    0 0 0 0 0
];

Mp = circshift(M, 1, 2);

ind = find(M);
indp = find(Mp.');

A = zeros(25, 25);
A(sub2ind(size(A), ind, ind)) = 1;
A(sub2ind(size(A), ind, indp)) = -1;

num2str(A(5:14, 5:14))
```

but it still doesn't yield the same result as the Python code in EDIT 1.

```
ans =

  10x28 char array

    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  1 -1  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  1 -1  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 -1  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0'
    '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1'
```

Comment: Numpy uses 0-based indexing but MATLAB uses 1-based indexing. Consider reading the documentations for [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and for [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MATLAB, you get relevant row and column subscripts of `A` returned by `im2var(M == 1)` of your targeted places for ones. This can alternately be done with `find(M.')` without the need to initialise `im2var` or just `find(M)` since `M` equals `transpose(M)` in your case. `find(M)` returns linear indices where `M` is not zero but the linear indices of `M` are the same as row and column subscripts of `A`. You cannot directly use these row and column subscripts and need to convert them into linear indices and then proceed i.e.

```matlab
ind = find(M);     % ind = find(M.'); in general
A(sub2ind(size(A),ind,ind)) = 1;
```

**P.S:** Note that MATLAB follows the column major order whereas NumPy follows the row major order.

Comment: Thank you so much! This certainly works for the identical indices case. I have updated my question to generalize for two sets of indices.

Comment: @Carpetfizz From your original question, it seemed that M and Mᵗ are same. I have edited the answer to rectify that issue.

Comment: Yes, I did forget to mention `Mp` initially - sorry! I tried your edit, but it's still not working.

Comment: @Carpetfizz And to answer that query, `A(6:15, 6:15)` is the result that you're expecting; not `A(5:14, 5:14)`. Indexing starts from 1 in MATLAB, not zero. And with the colon operator, both boundaries are included in MATLAB. Please see the documentation before using the function. MATLAB and NumPy are not one-to-one compatible